# Detect unmounted volumes on selected disk with PowerShell WMI or Diskpart

Tags: windows-7, powershell, command-line, wmi-query, wmic

How do I link **unmounted** volumes to physical disks?

Say I need to find and mount unmounted volumes on disk 3 as numbered by [Diskpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) or [WMIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation), or PowerShell WMI. How do I find out, with a script, what volumes of disk 3 aren't mounted? Or, alternatively, what physical disk a given unmounted volume (having no DriveLetter) resides on?

When a volume is unmounted, no logical disk or mount point exist for it. I suppose the relation can be found with `GetRelated` method, but I can't find such a code example suited for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate this code into the above answer:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Volume Where Name = 'D:\\'")

For Each objItem in colItems
    objItem.AddMountPoint("W:\\Scripts\\")
Next
```

It looks in Windows 7 PowerShell by using the Volume DeviceID instead of its DriveLetter, and relating the Volume to Disk 3 as shown in the above answer. A similar approach (AddMountPoint or Mount) can be used as above, but without using Diskpart.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). I think it is better to provide your own complete answer and acknowledge the other answer in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try, it will:

- Get all unmounted partitions for a given drive index `$targetDisk` using WMI
- Mount the discovered partitions on the target disk to the next available drive letter using a diskpart script.

Using the `GetRelated` method is all about knowing what you need to relate. It helps to know what WMI class represents what you are looking for `Win32_DiskPartition`. In your case you want to find the partitions which are not associated with a logical disk (unmounted) so we look for instances of `Win32_DiskPartition` which don't have an associated `Win32_LogicalDisk`.

Since you only want unmounted volumes on a particular physical disk we need to further associate classes. To do this we need to get `Win32_DiskPartition`'s associated `Win32_DiskDrive` instance.

```
$targetDisk = 3

$unmounted = gwmi -class win32_DiskPartition | ? {
    ($_.GetRelated('Win32_LogicalDisk')).Count -eq 0 
}

if ($unmounted) {
    $commands = @()
    $unmounted | ? { $_.GetRelated('Win32_DiskDrive') | ? { $_.Index -eq $targetDisk} } | % {
        $commands += "select disk {0}" -f $_.DiskIndex
        $commands += "select partition {0}" -f ($_.Index + 1)
        $commands += "assign"
    }

    $tempFile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
    $commands | out-file $tempFile -Encoding ASCII

    $output = & diskpart.exe /s $tempFile 2>&1
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        Write-Error $output
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Clear and helpful. Why did you prefer using Diskpart to mount the unmounted volumes? Is it possible to use WMI for that (like Add Mount) - if yes, can you give the script example?

Comment: @sambul35 I googled around a bit for how to do it and didn't find what I was looking for so I settled with diskpart. It's probably possible just wasn't going to spend all day looking.

Comment: @sambul35 Also I was using XP so some of the WMI classes weren't available like Win32_Volume.